# How does Spring multipart file upload exactly work?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I develope a fileserver that has to handle large file uploads (>1G B) with spring boot. How can I implement the upload when I do not want to use the main memory?

This is my code:

```
final String id = GenerationHelper.uuid();
    final File newFile = new File(id);
    LOG.info("New file: " + id + " with size " + content.getSize());
    if (!content.isEmpty()) {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalBytes = 0;

        try {
            in  = (FileInputStream) content.getInputStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer);
                totalBytes += bytesRead;
                LOG.info(bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to save file", e);
            newFile.delete();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Error creating new file with id " + id + ". Deleting this file...", e);
            }
        }
        LOG.info(totalBytes + " Bytes read");
    }
```

The log output starts after the file has been uploaded completely so I guess that the file has been already uploaded. Is it possible to write an upload directly to the filesystem?

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The multipart upload will be written to a temporary location on disk or held in memory. As explained in the javadoc for `MultipartFile`, it's then your responsibility to move the file to a permanent location before it's cleaned up at the end of the request processing.

> The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk. In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary storages will be cleared at the end of request processing.

You can move the contents (from memory or the temporary location on disk) by calling `MultiPartFile.transferTo(File)`.

Whether or not the file is held in memory or written to a temporary location depends on the underlying implementation. For example, Commons File Upload will store files less than 10240B in memory, with anything bigger being written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for this information! Do I have the possibility to validate the user data (username and password) bevor the upload starts? Or is the file already completely uploaded befor the soring controller is called?

Comment: I think that'd be better dealt with in a separate question

Comment: What exactly marks " end of the request processing" ?

Comment: @PhilipRego The end of request processing is when the call into application code has completed and execution has returned to the servlet container. At this point it cleans up the HTTP request and response objects that were passed into the application as they're no longer needed. Parts from a multipart request are deleted as part of this. [Here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/4329d123ea635dc9edf22c8a1ce5b8e6e526f6e6/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java#L291) is where Tomcat does it, for example.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thanks for that answer. I'm not fully clear on when the endpoint or a constraint validator is called. If I my endpoint should accept csv, but someone send an ISO (2gb) with csv extension... is it possible to validate it? This is to avoid wasting resources.

Comment: I understand your answer. But I have a problem. My application lets user to upload many files but after each upload, it seems that my application's memory consumption grows. I believe that after each upload process, spring should free up the spaces. Could you help me out?

Comment: @ToePyaeSoneOo Please ask a new question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).