# Access File in multipart/form-data in a stream like fashion in Spring Boot rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

following scenario: Service A receives a multipart/form-data request and needs to forward it to Service B.
Because the file in the request can be of arbitrary size, Service A needs to stream the file to Service B as soon as possible. At the moment Service A can receive the requests but Spring Boot will load the whole request/file into memory resulting in a really high memory footprint. I also tried the often suggested apache commons-fileupload package but without the expected result.

This leads me to the following question:

Is it even possible in spring boot to access the incomming http request in a stream like manner without loading the whole thing into the memory or a file ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to receive a value without [loading it into either memory or onto a temporary location on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298891/12393574).

If you look at the configuration, the value `spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB` defines at what point Spring should stop loading objects into memory, and instead start writing them to the disk.

If you still want to use a stream, it's easily done by accepting a MultipartFile and calling "getInputStream()"

```
@PostMapping
public void yourRequest(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

    // your code
    ...
}
```

Comment: The standard multipart resolver loads the wohle thing into memory or onto the disk....you have to disable the standard multipart resolver in spring boot and use the raw HttpServletRequest...